# Getting a -1 error when trying to insert in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I tried inserting some sample data in my database.

And initially got an error on my Logcat saying the column "movie_rating" is not null.

I commented out a section of code that seemed to make it complicated and didn't see the message again on logcat but still getting -1 when I check it with debugger.

Here's the github repo : https://github.com/Mf4z/Movie-bookmark/tree/debug-sample-insertion

1 - Here's the code for the sample insertion  :

```
public class DatabaseDataWorker {

    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    public DatabaseDataWorker(SQLiteDatabase db){

        this.mDb = db;
    }

    public void insertSampleMovies(){

        insertMovies("Big Bang Theory","Series","2","22","Hey Penny","15:12","5");
        insertMovies("Mr Robot","Series","1","2","Ones-and-zer0es","10:11","5");
    }



/*


  private void insertMovies(String name,String type,String timestamp,String rating) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_NAME,name);
        values.put(MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_TYPE,type);
        values.put(MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_TIMESTAMP,timestamp);
        values.put(MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_NAME,rating);

        String[] nullColumns = {MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_SEASON,
                MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_EPISODE,
                MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_EPISODE_NAME };

        long newRowId = mDb.insertOrThrow(MovieInfoEntry.TABLE_NAME, String.valueOf(nullColumns), values);
    }

*/

    private void insertMovies(String name,String type,String season,String episode,String epName,String timestamp,String rating) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_NAME,name);
        values.put(MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_TYPE,type);
        values.put(MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_SEASON,season);
        values.put(MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_EPISODE,episode);
        values.put(MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_EPISODE_NAME,epName);
        values.put(MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_TIMESTAMP,timestamp);
        values.put(MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_NAME,rating);

        long newRowId = mDb.insert(MovieInfoEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    }


}
```

2 - Here's the code for the database schema :

```
public class MovieBookmarkDatabaseContract {

    private MovieBookmarkDatabaseContract(){}

    public static final class MovieInfoEntry implements BaseColumns {

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "movie_info";
        public static final String COLUMN_MOVIE_NAME = "movie_name";
        public static final String COLUMN_MOVIE_TYPE = "movie_type";
        public static final String COLUMN_MOVIE_SEASON = "movie_season";
        public static final String COLUMN_MOVIE_EPISODE = "movie_episode";
        public static final String COLUMN_MOVIE_EPISODE_NAME = "movie_episode_name";
        public static final String COLUMN_MOVIE_TIMESTAMP = "movie_timestamp";
        public static final String COLUMN_MOVIE_RATING = "movie_rating";

        //CREATE INDEX movie_info_index ON movie_info(movie_name)
        public static final String INDEX1 = TABLE_NAME+"_index1";
        public static final String SQL_CREATE_INDEX1 =
                "CREATE INDEX " + INDEX1 + " ON " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_MOVIE_NAME + ")";


        /*  CREATE TABLE movie_info (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,movie_name TEXT NOT NULL,movie_type TEXT NOT NULL,
            movie_season TEXT NOT NULL,movie_episode  TEXT NOT NULL,movie_episode_name TEXT,
            movie_timestamp TEXT NOT NULL,movie_rating TEXT NOT NULL)
        */

        public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+
                _ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COLUMN_MOVIE_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                COLUMN_MOVIE_TYPE+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                COLUMN_MOVIE_SEASON +" TEXT, "+
                COLUMN_MOVIE_EPISODE +" TEXT, "+
                COLUMN_MOVIE_EPISODE_NAME +" TEXT, "+
                COLUMN_MOVIE_TIMESTAMP + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                COLUMN_MOVIE_RATING +" TEXT NOT NULL)";
    }
}
```

3 - The database helper class :

```
import com.emef4z.moviebookmark.MovieBookmarkDatabaseContract.MovieInfoEntry;

public class MovieBookmarkOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Moviebookmark.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MovieBookmarkOpenHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(MovieInfoEntry.SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(MovieInfoEntry.SQL_CREATE_INDEX1);

        DatabaseDataWorker worker = new DatabaseDataWorker(db);
        worker.insertSampleMovies();

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

4 - The class where it all comes together :

```
public class WatchingFragment extends Fragment {

    private MovieBookmarkOpenHelper mOpenHelper;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerItems;
    private MovieRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_list, container, false);

        mOpenHelper = new MovieBookmarkOpenHelper(getContext());

        initializeDisplayContent(rootView);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        mOpenHelper.close();
        super.onDestroyView();
    }


    private void initializeDisplayContent(View rootView){

        mRecyclerItems = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_list);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mAdapter = new MovieRecyclerAdapter(getContext(),null);

        displayMovies();

    }

    private void displayMovies() {
        mRecyclerItems.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerItems.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **insertMovies** method (both signatures) you are using the wrong column name for the **rating** i.e. you have

```
values.put(MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_NAME,rating);
```

When it would appear that you should have

```
values.put(MovieInfoEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_RATING,rating);
```

Thus the rating will be placed into the **movie_name** column and ***nothing*** (i.e. **null**) will be attempted to be inserted into the **rating** column and thus the **not null conflict**

This can clearly be seen from the message in the log :-

```
2019-11-19 10:45:05.586 22025-22025/com.emef4z.moviebookmark E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting movie_name=5 movie_type=Series movie_season=1 movie_timestamp=15:12 movie_episode=2 movie_episode_name=1_ones-and-zer0es
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: movie_info.movie_rating (code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)
```

The message itself is not a FATAL exception and is trapped by the SQLiteDatabase **insert** conveniece method (as it is designed to do) and thus the method returns -1 indicating that the row was not inserted.

P.S.

The shorter **insertMovies** method could be simply be :-

```
private void insertMovies(String name,String type,String timestamp,String rating) {
    insertMovies(name,type,null,null,null,timestamp,rating);
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help, much appreciated. Aha! I'll implement the shorter one like that. Many thanks.

Comment: @MarwanMai that's good. If the answer helped you then please tick it as answered.